# Different javascript navigator object for each cefsharp instance

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I want CefSharp to use different navigator object for each browser instance, but I can't find the solution.

I know it's possible to change some navigator properties in CefSettings, but thats only possible before initializing Cef and its shared between all browser instances.

I need to be able to run multiple browser instances, each with custom navigator properties (userAgent, appName, appVersion...). Changing these values while instance is running should also be possible.

I've tried to mock it by injecting javascript in `FrameLoadStart` event, using `ExecuteJavaScriptAsync` method, but the problem is that javascript is injected asynchronously and thats gambling in my opinion, because website javascript can get navigator object before its mocked by my script.

I need a solution that is 100% guaranteed to prevent websites from getting true browser informations from navigator object and deliver modified properties.

The best solution would be a way to set navigator object for each browser instance, but mocking it would be OK too, but I need a way to load and execute my script before website is starting to load.

Thanks for help!

Comment: `CEF` doesn't currently support user agent changing dynamically,  are the other properties derived from the `user agent`? You might be better suited switching to a different `CEF` wrapper, `CefGlue` or `ChromiumFx` where you can execute your script directly when the `V8Context` is created.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so... Here is the list of properties: https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-navigator-object
I need each browser instance to be unique. I've implemented everything they can only be detected with javascript fingerprinting...